# Sending bulk-messages using viber-api and node.js through web app

Tags: javascript, node.js, viber

Is there any way I can integrate viber's api to send bulk messages to viber contacts through web app ?
I have a web app that is SSL certified and a public account in viber.
This is their api: https://developers.viber.com/api/nodejs-bot-api/index.html

I can't seem to find the code that would let me send a message to multiple users. Any help with what I can use ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Better late than never) In 2019 we use this API https://developers.viber.com/rest/

**Broadcast Message**

Resource URL:

`https://chatapi.viber.com/pa/broadcast_message`

```
{
   "sender":{
      "name":"John McClane",
      "avatar":"http://avatar.example.com"
   },
   "min_api_version":2,
   "type":"rich_media",
   "broadcast_list":[
      "pttm25kSGUo1919sBORWyA==",
      "2yBSIsbzs7sSrh4oLm2hdQ==",
      "EGAZ3SZRi6zW1D0uNYhQHg==",
      "kBQYX9LrGyF5mm8JTxdmpw=="
   ],
   "type":"text",
   "text":"Hello World!"
}
```

**Post to Public Chat**

Resource URL:

`https://chatapi.viber.com/pa/post`

Post data:

```
{
   "from":"01234567890A=",
   "sender":{
      "name":"John McClane",
      "avatar":"http://avatar.example.com"
   },
   "type":"text",
   "text":"Hello World!"
}
```